# Using Digits by twitter in Android

Tags: android, twitter, amazon-cognito

I'd like to uses newly introduced Login Provider, Digits by Twitter. Everything works fine till the time I wanted to verify user credentials on a third party server (Amazon Cognito in my case) as described [here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/oauth-echo).

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = TwitterCore.getInstance().getAuthConfig();
TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();

OAuthSigning oauthSigning = new OAuthSigning(authConfig, authToken);
```

in my case `session.getAuthToken();` returns an instance of AuthToken not TwitterAuthToken which then I cannot pass it to `OAuthSigning()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply cast the AuthToken to TwitterAuthToken. If you are using with [Amazon Cognito](http://www.amazonaws.com/cognito/) you can use a block similiar to the following:

```
   @Override
   public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
       TwitterAuthToken authToken = (TwitterAuthToken)session.getAuthToken();
       String value = authToken.token + ";" + authToken.secret;
       Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
       logins.put("www.digits.com", value);
       // Note: This overrides any existing logins
       credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
   }
```